# LISP List Not Appending And Printing Twice

Tags: append, lisp

I'm quite new to LISP and I am trying to work on the cond statement for class. Currently, I am attempting to check if the value passed is a list and if so, append the letter d onto the list.

Here is my code:

```
(defun test(L)
(listp L)
(cond ((listp L) (append L (list 'd)))
)
(write L)
)
(test (list 'a 'b 'c))
```

The output I get is:

```
(A B C)

(A B C)
```

If I change the test to: `(test (car(list 'a 'b 'c)))`

The new output I get is:

```
A

A
```

Two things I am wondering is

1.) Why isn't D appended onto the list if the first test passes a list?

2.) Why are they being printed twice? I'm using LISP Works so I figure it's actually something with how it always outputs the final value or something.

Comment: could you please fix code formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) The same reason `str + "d"` doesn't mutate `str` in Java or Python. It creates a new list that you do not use!

```
>>> str + "d"
'abcd'
>>> str
'abc'
```

Crazy similar isn't it?

2.) In CL the `return` is the last evaluated expression. The REPL prints every top level expression result to the terminal. Python does this too:

```
>>> def test():
...  x = 2 + 3
...  print x
...  return x
... 
>>> test()
5
5
```

## Update

How to mutate the argument list. The simple answer is that you need to mutate the last pair of the argument instead:

```lisp
(defun test (l)
  (assert (consp 1) (l) "l needs to be a non nil list. Got: ~a" l)
  (nconc l (list 'd)
  (write l)))

(defparameter *test1* (list 1 2 3))
(defparameter *test1-copy* *test1*)
(test *test1*)            ; ==> (1 2 3 d) (and prints (1 2 3 d))
*test1*                   ; ==> (1 2 3 d)
*test1-copy*              ; ==> (1 2 3 d)
(eq *test1* *test1-copy*) ; ==> t

(test '())
** error l needs to be a non nil list. Got: NIL
```

`(nconc l x)` does `(setf (cdr (last l)) x)`

If you need to alter the binding, then you need to make a macro:

```
(defmacro testm (var)
  (assert (symbolp var) (var) "List needs to be a variable binding. Got: ~a" var)
  `(progn
     (when (listp ,var)
       (setf ,var (append ,var (list 'd)))
     (write ,var))))

(macroexpand '(testm *test2*))
; ==> (progn 
;       (when (consp *test2*)
;         (setf *test2* (append *test2* (list 'd))))
;       (write *test2*))

(defparameter *test2* (list 1 2 3))
(defparameter *test2-copy* *test2*)
(testm *test2*)           ; ==> (1 2 3 d) (and prints (1 2 3 d))
*test2*                   ; ==> (1 2 3 d)
*test2-copy*              ; ==> (1 2 3)
(eq *test2* *test2-copy*) ; ==> nil

(defparameter *x* nil)
(testm *x*)               ; ==> (d) (and prints (d))
*x*                       ; ==> (d)

(testm '(1))
** error List needs to be a variable binding. Got: '(1)
```

## Idiomatic way to do it

```
(defun test (list)
  (if (consp list)
      (append list '(d))
      list))

(write (test '(1 2 3)))
; ==> (1 2 3 d) (and prints (1 2 3 d))  

(defparameter *test3* '(1 2 3))
(setf *test3* (test *test3*))
*test3* ; ==> (1 2 3 d)
```

Comment: What would be the best way to have L become updated and write out L?

Comment: @KyleJ updated how to mutate and how to do it better.